# HTML table Modificaions

Tags: html, aurelia

I want to group records in html table according to category and display category as a full row before all group with some additional information. Data is in JSON format want to display in HTML format in Aurelia framework

[image: Ht]

Comment: please update your question with code sample. Add what you have tried so far, what error you get, etc..  You wont get any help just with a paragraph you post.

Comment: There I just used simple statement to get data from json file. I am not getting any error  but I dont know how to group the data   . I need to group data by  Group A , group B and show the sum of Amount.